# Multiple email seperated by semicolon regex

Tags: javascript, java, c#, regex, web

Hi guys i have a requirement such that i have to validate email addresses seperated by semicolon.For example "test@test.com; test@Tes.com" something like this.I am using the below regex :

```
(([^@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@;]{2,}\;{0,1}\s*))+
```

The problem here it the regex works even if there is no semicolon in between but with space eg `"test@test.com Test@tes.com"`.But That is not correct.so can anyone tell me how to achieve this?Also when there is a single email id no need of semi-colon in between

Comment: No..Its not the same.Actually that post was for regular expression.Mine i have the regular expression.But the space inbetween instead of semicolon also matching.Need to avoid that and how to do it is my question

Comment: Another common way to achieving your requirement is to split the email string using ; as separator and then test for email validation.

Answer (score 0):

found a working regex. Tested till 3 emails.

> ([^@]+@[^\s@]+.[^\s@;]{2,})+(\;([^@]+@[^\s@]+.[^\s@;]{2,}){1,1})*

Tested samples :

1. test@test.com;sample@google.com;dsdsd@dsd.sd -> true
2. test@test.com;sample@google.com dsdsd@dsd.sd -> false
3. test@test.com -> true
4. test@test.com; -> false

Key thing here is to follow \w+(.\w+)+ pattern. 
 Hope this helps

Comment: But when i try "test@test.com; test@tes.com",it fails.I also need spaces or no space which so ever after the colon.What should i do?

Comment: May I know why do you need spaces? In real world application spaces will be trimmed out for emails. So you can do a replaceAll(" ", "") before the regex matching.

Comment: Ok .That is ok..But i am also getting true for "test@test.com;test@tes.com;tes".Thats maily where i am also stuck

Answer (score 0):

Try regex  `(?!.*;$)^([-\w]+?@\w+\.\w+(?:\s*;\s*)?)+$`

This will match any no. of emails separated by a semicolon. The negative lookahead 
`(?!.*;$)` will not match email with a semicolon at last.

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/q6aZxt/4)

Comment: This 'test@test.com; test@Tes.com' should match because it has semicolon inside it doesn't matter extra space. It should not match if there is no semicolon and only space between two emails.

Comment: Thank you so much.This works like a gem.Just that what should i do if i need some special characters in mail id like "xyz-xyz@test.com" ,because it is not accepting characters like '-'

Comment: Add what you want to include inside `[-\w]`